# At what tier does consistent hashing get implemented?

Tags: hashing

Where does the code for consistent hashing reside? I have read how it is implemented (at a high level), but am unsure if it is exposed as a microservice between the web server and the app servers or on each app server (would seem unlikely).

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Could you [edit] your question to give us some background and context?  It sounds like you read something; perhaps you could summarize what you've read and maybe a reference or citation or link to it?

Comment: So I read that consistent hashing is a way to determine which server handles an incoming request. Regardless of the source, this is the summary of its intended use. What I am unsure of is the sequence. For example, is it client -> server containing consistent hashing code -> client -> server ?

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing?  If so it is implementation-specific where it is implemented.